# iPad App - how to change UITableViewCell style?

Tags: ipad, xcode4, uitableview, styles

Again I'm moving from Xcode 3 to 4 and finding that some things are different.  I'm writing a splitview iPad app and working from all the code that was generated for me.  In the master view I want to customize the `UITableViewCell` to use the `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` style.   In the past that was simple and I knew it was done within `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

In the new template code there is no `[[UITableViewCell alloc] init....]`  there is only

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

so I can't modify the style here.  I looked in the storyboard and found the cell but cannot seem to change the property there either.

In short, I can't find where the UITableViewCells are alloc/init'ed so that I can make my change.   Where is this done in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the storyboard-based template, the cell is created by the storyboard, so you need to configure it in the storyboard in IB. If you haven't found that, it's here:

[image]

Select the cell, and it'll be in the attributes inspector. While you're there you might want to set a reuse identifier you can use in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

(You can also use IB to change the font or other properties of the cell's `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` and set accessory styles like you would have before in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.)

Answer (score -1):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
```

This is still done in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: There is no block of if(cell==nil){...} in the template code and if I add one it is never equal nil.  So it must be initialized elsewhere, that is my problem.   I did notice that if I change the default reuseIdentifier from @"Cell" to @"myCell" it will fire and I can init it myself there, but I'd rather find out where it's actually initialized.